# What format(s) does Blender 2.6 support well enough to use with my game?

Tags: blender, file-format, model-loader

I'm using Blender 2.6 to create meshes to be loaded by my engine while in development. I've noticed that Blender 2.6 has very few exporters compared to previous versions of Blender (but a MUCH improved UI). I was using the FBX exporter since there is the FBX SDK to keep the model loading code from being too large (as opposed to a Collada parser). It seems that FBX wasn't such a good choice since I've started to notice that the exporter is terrible (It doesn't export light DecayType, material colors/intensity and many other things, it leaves them at zero).

What exporter in Blender DOES work well? I'd prefer one that exports to XML since it can be opened in a text editor to fix the paths.

Comment: What is the light DecayType? Are you talking about light falloff curves? And what do you mean with colors/intensity? You should be aware that blender won't create shaders for you when exporting. Usually you have other means to control color/specularity in a game engine (via diffuse/specular maps).

Comment: DecayType is the Attenuation type (Quadratic, Constant,...). FBX has properties for Ambient/Diffuse/Specular colors and intensity(factor) but the exporter sets all of these to zero regardless of what they are in the scene. These values are the means to control such values in the game engine - The exporter is just ignoring them.

Answer (score 1):

The number of exporters is irrelevant, since you only need one!

The quality of the exporter is more important. If you're writing your own engine, I'd suggest you write your own Blender exporter so you can get it to work exactly the way you want it and support the same feature set that your engine does. The blender python API is easy to work with, the only drawback is that it's sometimes a moving target, meaning that scripts sometimes have to be updated when Blender is improved.